# Cannot read property 'createStore' of undefined Redux Babel 6

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, babeljs

I am currently running into an issue where the createStore method is undefined.

Upon further inspection I am unsure if this is related directly to redux or babel but here goes.

When I attempt to boot my app I am confronted by an error `Cannot read property 'createStore' of undefined` while debugging this error I ran into this:

```
var _redux = __webpack_require__(184);
var _redux2 = _interopRequireDefault(_redux);
// This function does not place _redux2 in the default object
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
// _redux2.default is undefined here:
var store = _redux2.default.createStore(function (state) {
    return state;
}, window.PROPS);
```

FYI I am importing the module with es6 like so:

```
import Redux from 'redux'
Redux.createStore()
```

I have also tried:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
createStore()
```

Because redux exports `__esModule` as true redux doesn't get wrapped in the default object which is why it's saying its undefined.

The method `createStore` does however exist on the _redux2 object.

I am unsure why this is happening as all other modules appear to import fine?

Comment: Ever find a fix? I am having the same issue. Maybe create an issue here? https://github.com/reactjs/redux

Comment: unfortunately not. This project was put on the back burner so i haven't touched it since :/